# Running Javascript Function only when linked from certain page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to be able to toggle a javascript function that opens a certain tab on my page when the page loads. However I only want this function to run automatically when coming from another page.

For example:

Page A has the function that opens said tab, which is triggered when clicking on a button normally.

I want the user to click a button on page B and redirect to page A, where the function on page A automatically triggers.

However if the user reaches page A from anywhere but page B I do not want this function to trigger automatically.

This is the best way I can describe it, any help would be great. (I should also mention this is being done is ASP.NET MVC4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use document.referrer. Something like this.

```
if (document.referrer === 'pageB') {
  // trigger the function
}
```